# Quasar hide parent if child element is empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I have this code:

```
<q-expansion-item
  default-opened
  expand-icon="keyboard_arrow_down"
  class="q-pa-none q-ma-none"
>
      <template v-slot:header>
        <div class="full-width text-subtitle2 text-grey q-ma-xs">Today</div>
      </template>
      <div
        v-for="(item, indexItem) in mondayTask"
      >
        <TaskCard
          :items="item"
          v-show="item.show"
        /></div
 ></q-expansion-item>
```

Sometimes there will be no `TaskCard` shown, so I don't want to show the `q-expansion-item`

Is there any solution to solve it?

Comment: `<q-expansion-item v-if="mondayTask.length" ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, You want to hide `q-expansion-item` if show property contains `false` value in all the objects of `mondayTask` array. If Yes, checking for `mondayTask.length` will not work. You have to just check for the show property value in each object with the help of [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data: {
    mondayTask: [{
      name: 'Task 1',
      show: false
    }, {
      name: 'Task 2',
      show: true
    }, {
      name: 'Task 3',
      show: false
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.9.1/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.9.1/dist/quasar.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons"/>
<div id="q-app">
  <q-expansion-item
                    v-if="mondayTask.some(({ show }) => show)"
                    default-opened
                    expand-icon="keyboard_arrow_down"
                    class="q-pa-none q-ma-none"
                    >
    <template v-slot:header>
      <div class="full-width text-subtitle2 text-grey q-ma-xs">Today</div>
    </template>
    <div v-for="(item, indexItem) in mondayTask" :key="indexItem">
      <q-card v-show="item.show">
        <q-card-section>
          {{ item.name }}
        </q-card-section>
      </q-card>
    </div>
  </q-expansion-item>
</div>
```

To play with the above code snippet, Just update the `show` property value from `true` to `false` in the 2nd object of `mondayTask` data object.